CodeGolf - как в Linq вызвать объект на котором он был вызван?
Есть следующий код :
var data = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int[]>(Console.ReadLine()).ToList();
Console.Write(data.Zip(data.Skip(1), (f, s) => f == s).Count(x => x));

Он работает корректно, но можно ли его ещё сильнее сократить? Я вызываю переменную "data" дважды. Сперва на ней вызывается метод Zip, а потом она же выступает в качестве аргумента в этом методе. Можно ли как-то в методе указать, что аргументом нужно брать объект на котором он был вызван?
Или может быть тут как-то можно сделать через вызов другого метода? В общем возможно ли решить данную задачу в одну строчку?
Сама задача, которую решает код вот :
У вас есть переменная data которая содержит входные пользовательские данные.
data - список из элементов целых числел.
Напишите код, который находит количество серий из подряд идущих одинаковых чисел.
Результат записать в переменную result.
Например, в таком списке [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4] - 6 серий

В качестве аргумента выступает не data, а data.Skip - совсем другая последовательность.

Вообще тут либо формулировка кривая, либо я чего-то не понимаю. "Количество серий" - тут же 3 серии (из двоек, троек и четвёрок), а ответ при этом 6. Этот ответ мог бы подойти под "суммарное количество элементов в сериях подряд идущих элементов", например. И код пэто и считает - количество элементов, равных предыдущему.

@Alexander Petrov формулировка задачи да, кривая. Имеется ввиду, что нужно найти количество пар последовательно идущих одинаковых элементов. Сам код задачу решает. Загвоздка лишь в том, можно ли как-то запихнуть всё в одно выражение.

Был бы это Питон, можно было бы чуть короче написать, сделав просто sum без аргументов в конце, он бы сам bool в int перевёл. Но в C# так нельзя, придётся тип приводить и станет ещё длиннее. А что касается два раза data в выражении, то это неизбежно, поскольку нам нужно взять один раз как есть его, а в торой раз со смещением на 1, это никак не обойти.

Enumerable.Range(0, data.Length - 1).Aggregate(0, (count, idx) => data[idx] == data[idx + 1] ? ++count : count) выполняет задачу в одну строку.

@Mark Shcerbakov у нас data это JsonSerializer.Deserialize<int[]>(Console.ReadLine()).ToList() основная проблема в этом. Её не получится несколько раз в выражение подставлять.

а зачем массив в список превращать?

.ToList() можно и нужно убрать. .Count(x => x) можно просто написать как .Count(). Вам нужно буков в коде меньше или скорость больше?

@aepot .Count() выполнит подсчет кол-ва всех элементов полученной последовательности. А вот как у автора написано, выполнит подсчет только true значений =) Так что там все верно =)

@MarkShcerbakov согласен

var (result, _) = data.Aggregate((0, (int?)null), (acc, nxt) => (nxt == acc.Item2 ? ++acc.Item1 : acc.Item1, nxt));
Console.Write(result);


Спасибо. Это именно то что нужно. В конце только .Item1 добавить нужно, что бы выводил искомое значение.

Конкретно в данном случае используется деконструкция кортежа var (result, _) , чтобы не обращаться к элементу Item1.

@Pavel, поправил ответ чтобы было понятно что имеется ввиду

По сути вам надо хранить предыдущие значение и количество серии на каждой итерации. Для этого есть метод Aggregate в Linq. Который может это хранить у себя и вернуть как результат эту структуру, а из ней уже можно взять количество серии

"[1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4]" - входные данные отсортированы или это пример такой неудачный?
Если отсортированы, то можно подойти к решению задачи аналитически, и всё упрощается:
using System;
using System.Linq;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var nums = Console.ReadLine().Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
        Console.WriteLine(nums.Length - nums.Distinct().Count());
    }
}

Количество серий из подряд идущих одинаковых чисел равно разнице общего количества чисел и количества уникальных чисел. Если в массиве из N чисел число одно, то количество серий, очевидно, равно N-1, потому что первое число не даёт серию. Каждое новое число уменьшает количесво серий на 1, отсюда и решение.
Если не отсортированы, то тогда я бы сделал так:
using System;
using System.Linq;
static class Program {
    static void Main() {
        var nums = Console.ReadLine().Split(',').Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();
        int q = 0, k = nums.Length;
        for (int i = 1, j = nums[0]; i < k; j = nums[i++]) if (nums[i] == j) q++;
        Console.WriteLine(q);
    }
}

